# How to return value from foreach?

Tags: c#, linq

I want iterate over my `List<T>` and return the total of the method `GetProfit`, and save this inside a variable, so I did:

```
decimal profit = bets.Where(c => c.Tags.ToLower().Contains(tag)).ToList()
                      .ForEach(c => GetProfit(c.Status, c.Stake, c.Odds));
```

the compiler say:

> Cannot implicit cast void to decimal

Comment: You want `Select`, not `ForEach` - `Select` "maps" each value to a projected value and returns an enumerable of those, whereas `ForEach` has no capability to return a result.

Comment: Please share `GetProfi` implementation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `ForEach` construct returns `void` hence the compilation error, instead use the `Select` clause to map from a type `T` to `decimal` then `Sum`.

```
bets.Where(c => c.Tags.ToLower().Contains(tag))
    .Select(c => GetProfit(c.Status, c.Stake, c.Odds))
    .Sum();
```

or Simply:

```
bets.Where(c => c.Tags.ToLower().Contains(tag))     
    .Sum(c => GetProfit(c.Status, c.Stake, c.Odds));
```